# How to send a vector to php file?

Tags: php, mysql, blackberry, vector

I am writing a program about drawing a route of a person with using initial GPS values of that person.

To do that I have implemented all locationListener code and I put all coordinate values into a vector. But the problem that I have now is that, I want to put them into mySQL and I dont know how to send a vector to Php file. Can you please help me with that ?

Note : I do not want to send values via URL so thats why I want to send the whole vector.

```
package project;

import java.util.Vector;

import javax.microedition.location.Location;
import javax.microedition.location.LocationException;
import javax.microedition.location.LocationListener;
import javax.microedition.location.LocationProvider;

import net.rim.device.api.gps.BlackBerryCriteria;
import net.rim.device.api.gps.BlackBerryLocationProvider;
import net.rim.device.api.gps.GPSInfo;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.FieldChangeListener;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ButtonField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;

public class RoutePaint extends MainScreen implements LocationListener,
        FieldChangeListener {

    public double latitude;
    public double altitude;
    public double longitude;
    public float velocity;
    public Vector locations;

    private BlackBerryCriteria myCriteria;
    private BlackBerryLocationProvider myProvider;
    private Point point;

    private ButtonField locVector;


    public RoutePaint() {

        locations = new Vector();
        locVector = new ButtonField("Locations Vector",
                ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
        locVector.setChangeListener(this);


        add(locVector);

        myCriteria = new BlackBerryCriteria(GPSInfo.GPS_MODE_AUTONOMOUS);
        try {
            myProvider = (BlackBerryLocationProvider) LocationProvider
                    .getInstance(myCriteria);

        } catch (LocationException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        myProvider.setLocationListener(this, 3, -1, -1);

    }

    public void locationUpdated(LocationProvider provider, Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        point = new Point();
        latitude = location.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLatitude();
        altitude = location.getQualifiedCoordinates().getAltitude();
        longitude = location.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLongitude();
        velocity = location.getSpeed();
        point.x = latitude;
        point.y = longitude;

        locations.addElement(point);

        invalidate();
    }

    public void providerStateChanged(LocationProvider arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public boolean onClose() {

        Dialog.inform("Exiting project!");
        System.exit(0);
        return true;
    }

    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {

        if (field == locVector) {
            getUiEngine().pushScreen(new LocationsVector(locations));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So do you want to send them as HTTP Post or feed it directly into the MySQL database?

Comment: While searching on the net I ve seen HTTp Post but I didnt understand how to send because I havent used Http post before. 
Also, if it is possible to send it directly to mySQL, i can also use. I dont know how to do it too :)

Comment: you will have to specify language to get a decent answer on that.

Comment: here i put the code where i put the coordinates into a vector, so now how can i send them into php file or directly to mySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the overall game plan is:

1. what you need is to send data using a POST request (`"Content-Type"` header should be `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`).
2. you should use your custom data format to be sent over the net, so the data can be easily parsed in PHP script.
3. inside of your PHP script you get the data, parse it to an array of Points and use SQL to put it to the DB.

A sample post data in your case could look as the following:

```
point_1_x=12.34&point_1_y=12.34&point_2_x=14.34&point_2_y=14.34
```

Here for a Point you have a pair of params (`point_N_x` and `point_N_y`, where `N` is index in your `Vector`). However the exact format is up to you. The only reason to know the format is to be able to write a parser on web part. I am sure you are able to generate smth similar (most likely more compact) by iterating through the `Vector`.

Googling you can find some examples on how to send a POST request on BB. For instance, look [here](http://vasudevkamath.techfiz.com/general/posting-data-via-http-from-blackberry/) and [here](http://randywestergren.com/?p=191) as a starting point. Also make sure you have studied the [official API](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/javax/microedition/io/HttpConnection.html) (scroll to "Example using POST with HttpConnection").

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I'm not quite from this field, but how long is the vector value, how does it look ? Maybe you could actually HTTP post it to the php file, if you want you could encode the values as Base64 (this way, at least it won't be so obvious as to what you're sending/not open text) or something like that .. ?

Comment: Actually, the length of the vector can be changed according to the length of the route of the user. So I can not say anything about the length. 
I am adding the code maybe you can help me.

Comment: ok, I was just coming by, noticed your post, while I am not even familiar with Java, I know that a vector holds a collection of objects, in a case of GPS location tracking, I suppose it would hold an array of GPS coordinates. This you can always present as a comma (or any other char) separated piece of Text, you can "serialize" and/or Gzip it, etc.. then Http post it to the php file, that would update a MySQL database.. (again, is the database ready ? will the vector items represent a row record in the table, etc..?)